# Show that there is not any irreducible algebraic set bigger than irreducible algebraic set $V(F)$. "Algebraic Curve, Exercise 1.39(b)"

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

I was trying to solve problem 1.39(b) from Fulton Algebraic Curve which is:

(a) Let $R$ be a UFD, and let $P = (t)$ be a principal, proper, prime ideal. Show that there is no prime ideal $Q$ such that $0 \subset Q \subset P$, $Q \neq 0, Q \neq P$. (b) Let $V = V(F)$ be an irreducible hypersurface in $A^n$. Show that there is no irreducible algebraic set $W$ such that $V \subset W \subset A^n, W \neq V, W \neq A^n$.

I thought part (b) should be direct result of part (a) but I have a problem. We don't know that $F$ is irreducible (which I think is needed) and I don't know why I should assume that $I(V(F))$ is equal to (F) here. What I missed?

Comment: suppose F factors and try to use the fact that V(F) is irreducible to get a contradiction.

Comment: We have $V(F^2) = V(F)$ for reducible polynomial $F^2$ and it doesn't lead me to any contradiction. Am I wrong? @Timkinsella

Comment: yes sorry i should have said "assume F has two distinct irreducible factors"

Comment: Ohhh, I can see now, using kaplansky theorem for UFD it is easy to show that $F$ should be power of a prime and else is easy, thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, Answering your own question is legit here so,

Let polynomial $F$ be power of a prime. Since $F = p^n$ and $(p^n) \subset (p) \subset \text{Rad}(F)$ and $p$ is irreducible so $\text{Rad}(F) = (p)$ and everything else is just result of part (a).

Now, it is enough to show that $F$ is power of a prime. Suppose $F$ has at least two distinct prime factors. Since $\text{Rad}(F)$ is prime, by kaplansky theorem for UFD, there is at least one prime element $p \in \text{Rad}(F)$. By definition of radical ideal we have $p^n \in (F)$ for some $n$, so $p^n = Fr$ for some $r \in R$ which leads us to contradiction because $F$ has distinct prime factors but $p^n$ doesn't.